# Syntax error in printing image pointing to a link in php

Tags: php, syntax

The following line is supposed to print a list item which is a variable picture that points to a variable link

```
  echo '<li><a href='http://www.twitter.com/'".$person."'>
          <img src ="'.$person.'.jpg'.'"/></a></li>';
```

I am getting the following error though

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
```

I am pretty sure I've screwed up the syntax in the `a href` part as I'm not quite sure how to handle the variables in the URLs...

Help is appreciated....Thanks!

Comment: Your quotes don't match. You're delimiting the PHP with singles, then switching to delimiting the HTML with singles and delimiting the HTML with doubles. What? SO's own code highlighting makes it obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use variable interpolation there.

```
echo "<li><a href='http://www.twitter.com/$person'><img src='$person.jpg'/></a></li>";
```

Comment: I was the faster gun ! ah! /joke

Comment: Yes, but fail for not bothering to explain the problem despite it being so simple.

Comment: works!...but I could have sworn I did this and it didn't work. Does it matter if it's '<li>................</li>'?

Answer (score 1):

Why did you change the quote lol

```
echo "<li>
           <a href='http://www.twitter.com/'".$person."'>
              <img src ="'.$person.'.jpg'.'"/>
           </a>
     </li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using printf/sprintf; these two functions will make it a lot easier to deal with modifications to your code in the future as well as make it so that you're not "jumping in" and "jumping out" of quote sections a lot.  It's a great way to avoid these kind of syntax problems with inline variables in double-quoted strings.

EDIT: The doc pages:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php